# Naming PHP object children in for loop

Tags: php, variables, loops

I want to do this:

```
<?php echo $factuurgegevens->aantal.$i; ?>
```

But it doesn't work, how can I handle this?

So I have to get:

```
<?php echo $factuurgegevens->aantal1; ?>
<?php echo $factuurgegevens->aantal2; ?>
<?php echo $factuurgegevens->aantal3; ?>
<?php echo $factuurgegevens->aantal4; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use curly braces (`{}`) to make up the dynamic [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php):

```
$name = 'aantal';
for($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++)
   echo $factuurgegevens->{$name . $i};
```

However you should really use an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) because that is made for things like this:

```
$factuurgegevens->aantal = array();
$factuurgegevens->aantal[1] = 'something';
$factuurgegevens->aantal[2] = 'something';
$factuurgegevens->aantal[3] = 'something';
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
$name = 'aantal';
for($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++)
   echo $factuurgegevens->{$name . $i};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by placing your string in a variable.

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
$var = 'aantal'.$i;

echo $factuurgegevens->$var;

}
```